# How to make multiple parallax layers using Scrollmagic?

Tags: javascript, css, parallax, scrollmagic

I'm trying to make use of Scrollmagic library to make parallax sections with two or more layers in them scrolling with different speed. Can't figure 
it out from examples on the website...

What I want is for instance one background layer with sky, on top of it clouds moving, and another on top of it with birds all scrolling top to bottom with different speed.

Some advice would be appreciated.